# Creating a structure for linked list

Tags: c, data-structures

Experts,
    I am having a simple doubt in linked list and structure. I want to create a list with subset. My example structure is

```
 typedef struct {
  uint16 a;
  uint8 b;
  uint8 c;
  uint8 d;
}subset_t;

typedef struct node{
   subset_t list;
   uint8 set_no;
   struct node *link;
}all_list:
```

But I think this structure will not do what I expect, Say for example there is a set number 15, in the set there should be different subset(a,b,c,d).

Ex.

```
    set                     subset
     15                     a=10; b=1; c=17; d=12
                            a=00, b=43; c=21; d=15;

     10                     a=10; b=1; c=17; d=12
                            a=00, b=43; c=21; d=15;
```

**How can I defined a structure for this**?. The main reason I want to create a different structure is to delete any of the subset easily.

Comment: Are there always going to be two sets of a/b/c/d per node as in the example, is the number of sets variable?  If always two, then each `node` will want two `subset_t` entries.  If there's a variable number, then you probably want to add a `struct subseet_t *next` element to your `subset_t` structure: the `node`s will give you a linked-list of `set_no`s, each with a `list` that heads a linked-list of set quadruples.

Comment: Thanks for reply, no it is not always two. I told for example.

Comment: You mean, the struct subseet_t *next is replace by struct node *link

Comment: No, see my answer as a starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want probably something like:

```
typedef struct subset_t {
  uint16 a;
  uint8 b;
  uint8 c;
  uint8 d;
  struct subset_t *next;
}subset_t;

typedef struct node{
   subset_t list;
   uint8 set_no;
   struct node *link;
}all_list:
```

(Note `subset_t` added to first line).  You run through `node` structures until `set_no` is the one you want.  Then that node's `list` is the head of a linked-list of `subset_t` strucutres with `next` pointing to the next in the list.

Comment: So I will having two head. One for all_list and other for subset_t? am I right

Comment: No, you have one head with a main list. From every entry in this main list, a sublist can start, so every entry in the main list can be the head of its own sublist.